# In JS, why can a function's parentheses be skipped, if the first argument is an fstring?

Tags: javascript

The title says it.

Here's what I mean:

```js
console.log`insert text here`
```

This is valid JS, which I found in a solution to a CodeWars kata, in the shape of ``` string.split`` ``` and ``` array.join`` ```.

After some playing around in node.js, this is what I found:

```js
> console.log`insert text here`
[ 'insert text here' ]

> console.log(`insert text here`)
insert text here

> console.log([`insert text here`])
[ 'insert text here' ]

> console.log`one`,`two`
[ 'one' ]
'two'

> console.log`one`,'two'
[ 'one' ]
'two'

> console.log`one`,'two',3
[ 'one' ]
3

> console.log'one'
             ^^^^^
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Turns out, that it actually logs an array, containing only the string.

How does this even work, what is causing this behaviour, and why is an error not thrown, *only* if it's an fstring?

Comment: Here you can check how tagged functions work: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-are-tag-functions-97682f29521b

Comment: it's called tagged templates https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

Comment: TIL `console.log` is a tagged function too.

Comment: @Oluwafemi There's no such thing as "tagged functions", only _calling normal functions with tagged literals_.